# Why Const is often used in object declaration while its properties could be changed?

Tags: javascript

my question is simple about `Const`. i have seen a lot places that devs prefer `const` over `let` and `var` while declaring object even its properties are mutable. Could somebody explain this?

```
const a = {};
a.name = "";
console.log(a.name);
```

Comment: `const` create an immutable reference so you won't be able to assign any other value to it. `let` create a common reference but bounded into the scope (you won't be able to use it outside the function).

Comment: `const a = {};` just implies that `a` will always be that same object, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prevents `a` (in your example) from being assigned a different reference, but properties within the object are often needed to be changed as they convey the current state of the object instance.

A simply analogy, which is more correct here?

```
var me = "Scott"; 
const me = "Scott";
```

What should happen if this then happens?

```
me = you;
```

Let's forget the fact that, in real life, you can change you name if you really want to. In this case `me` should always and forever reference, well, me - "Scott" so `const` is the better declaration.

But, over my lifetime, characteristics of me will change, some that are out of my control and some that are in my control. So, while we don't want the `me` reference to change to reference a different object, aspects of the object that `me` does reference should be able to be changed:

```
const me = {};
me.height = "6' 1";  // Used to be 6' 3" back in the day!
```

But, if you needed a constant value to hold in an object, you could declare a private variable in a constructor function to do that.

```
function Me(height){
  // Some aspects of this object will never change. They can be set up
  // as private data:
  const bloodType = "B+";

  // Others are just properties:
  this.height = height;
}
```

Or, you could continue to use an object literal, but you'd need to "lock down" certain properties so that become read-only. This is done with **[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)**.

Comment: There’s also `Object.freeze`.

Comment: @Xufox How would `Object.freeze` keep one value within an object constant? `.freeze()` freezes the entire object.

Comment: Right, you said “a constant value”, not “all values constant”. Sure, `Object.freeze` would keep all values constant; keeping only a single one constant would be done differently.

Comment: But then `Object.defineProperty(`…`, "`…`", {value: `…`, writable: false, configurable: false, enumerable: true});` would also work.

Comment: @Xufox Still don't get the `.freeze()` comment. Doesn't relate to what I said. But, yes, `Object.defineProperty` can certainly help here.

Answer (score 1):

Simply to prevent the object itself being overwritten or having its type changed. The constant will always be an object.

```
const a = {};
a = 'foo';
```

```
const b = {};
b = { foo: 'bar' };
```

Both will throw:

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

The `const` **declaration** creates a read-only reference to a value. It does **not** mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its parameters) can be altered.